# How to see inside an installed Karaf feature

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

How to see what an installed Karaf feature have inside?

Does it have other features in it?

What bundles and with what start-level does it install?

I talking about features like `cxf` of `http`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
feature:info <featurename>
```

to get details about the feature. It shows dependent features, bundle and config for this feature.

If you want even more details you can check the feature repos:

```
feature:repo-list
```

Each install feature repo will be shown with a mvn uri. 
For example for cxf 3.2.5 you would see.

```
cxf-3.2.5 mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.2.5/xml/features
```

Karaf can directly display the content of these urls

```
cat mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.2.5/xml/features
```

This will display the xml of the cxf feature. You can also find this directly in the maven central repo.

If a feature does strange things during its installation then there is also a way to debug:

```
feature:install -v http
```

This will install the karaf http feature and on the way log in detail what is done. Like bundles being deinstalled, installed, refreshed, restart, configs being deployed. This helps a lot when things do not go like expected.

Comment: I would add `-t` option to first command - it will display a whole list of dependencies and its dependencies. Might be verbose but that's real way to get everything contained in feature. ;-)

Comment: Nice. I did not know the -t option.